# Programmatically control play/pause on R-Shiny slider with Animation

Tags: r, shiny

I wish to have the user manipulate a slider to answer a question. To see if they are correct, the slider will move to the correct answer after they click, "Check". The pie chart will move at the same time. I think that this may be possible using Shiny with the slider animation options. However, I do not know how to turn the animation on and off programmatically. Or if it's possible to have the slider decrease in value - to move from 80% to 60% for example.

You can simulate the desired behaviour if you run the code below. The slider starts at 60. Push play and push pause when the slider gets to 80. How is it possible to programmatically do the same thing? ie Press the "Check" button and the pie slice automatically expands from 40% to 60%.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ui <- fluidPage(


  # App title ----
  titlePanel("How Many Canadians Speak French?"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar to demonstrate various slider options ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Size of slice A, B is determined automagically
      sliderInput("per_a", "Percent French Speaking",
                  min = 0, max = 100,
                  value = 60, step = 1,
                  animate = animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = TRUE)),
      actionButton(
        inputId = "check",
        label = "Check"
      )
    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "pieChart")

    )
  )
)


# Define server logic for slider examples ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- data.frame(
    group = c("English", "French"),
    value = c(40, 60)
  )

  # Functions
  draw_plot <- function(df) {
    bp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = group)) +
      geom_bar(width = 1, size = 1, color = "grey23", stat = "identity")

    pie <- bp + coord_polar("y", start = 0)
    pie + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.grid = element_blank(),
            legend.position = "none",
            axis.ticks = element_blank(),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 19, face = "bold")) +
      geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(value), "% ", c("English", "French"))), 
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
                color = "white", size = 6) +
      labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, title = "") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("red4", "#003399")) # Pie chart colours: English, French
  }

  output$pieChart <- renderPlot({
    df$value[2] <- input$per_a
    df$value[1] <- 100 - input$per_a
    draw_plot(df)
  })

  observeEvent(input$check, {
    # Insert code here that starts the slider animation at current value and stops it at 80
   })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```